# Should I worry about a PNY CS131122 SSD health status being at 77%?

Tags: ssd, physical-wear

I just checked today the S.M.A.R.T. info and says 77% good. Should I'll be worry about?

Is a PNY CS131122 with 480GB of total disk space.

Currently has 320GB available.

I didn't notice anything wrong, seems to work fine.

```
           Model : PNY CS1311 480GB SSD
        Firmware : CS131122
   Serial Number : PNY0916***********
       Disk Size : 480,1 GB (8,4/137,4/480,1/480,1)
     Buffer Size : Desconocido
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 937703088
   Rotation Rate : ---- (SSD)
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ACS-2
   Minor Version : ----
   Transfer Mode : SATA/600 | SATA/600
  Power On Hours : 11375 horas
  Power On Count : 4948 veces
     Host Writes : 18940 GB
     Temperature : 30 C (86 F)
   Health Status : Bueno (77 %)
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, NCQ, TRIM
       APM Level : 00FEh [ON]
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : C:


-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 100 100 _50 000000000000 Read Error Rate
09 100 100 __0 000000002C6F Power on Hours
0C 100 100 __0 000000001354 Power Cycle Count
A8 100 100 __0 000000000000 SATA PHY Error Count
AA 100 100 _10 000000000199 Bad Block Count
AD 100 100 __0 000000170035 Erase Count
C0 100 100 __0 00000000009F Unexpected Power Loss Count
C2 _70 _70 _30 001E001E001E Temperature
DA 100 100 _50 000000000000 Number of CRC Error
E7 100 100 __0 00000000004D SSD Life Left
F1 100 100 __0 0000000049FC Host Writes
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the full SMART results.

Comment: @DavidPostill Done.